# How to change the size of emojis in the twemojis package?

Tags: size, emoji

How can I change the size of emojis from `\usepackage{twemojis}` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\setlength{\twemojiDefaultHeight}{<value>}`to change the size of the emojis.

Comment: You can also scale individual emojis with `\twemoji[scale=<factor>]{<value>}`, specify an exact height or width with `\twemoji[width=<width>]{<value>}`. Finally you can use `\texttwemoji{<value>}` to create an emoji that automatically scales with the font size of the surrounding text.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Very kind ;-)